# How to encrypt information with different keys, but have ability to confirm it is same info encrypted

Tags: algorithm, encryption

So the problem is:

1) There is a plaintext string "Hello"

2) **A** encrypts it with their private key

3) **B** encrypts it with its private key

4) There must be a way to confirm that both encrypted messages are result of same information.

So if I have A's encrypted message and B's encrypted message, I can tell this is same encrypted info without getting original message.

An example:
A buys a message from B. A has encrypted information, and when he receives message encrypted with A's public key, he want's to be sure, that B doesn't lie to him and actually sends information, which is firstly encrypted with B's public key

Comment: *"There must be a way to confirm that both encrypted messages are result of same information"* -- why must there?

Comment: encrypted message should reveal no information about the plaintext (it's called *semantic security*) when done properly. Would be a solution to provide a plaintext hash? it would be possible to compare the hashes without revealing the original message

Comment: Dear Martin, I want to find an algorithm, where there is a way of confirming that both ciphertextes are result of same message without revealing the original message.

Comment: The situation: A buys a message from B. A has encrypted information, and when he receives message encrypted with his public key, he want's to be sure, that B doesn't lie to him and actually sends information, which is encrypted with B's private key.

Comment: Ok now I understand your question. Although I'm not sure if this is possible, with RSA?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27536/is-it-possible-to-get-an-rsa-encryption-key-by-comparing-the-unencrypted-and-enc

Comment: @YuriStiopin: `A encrypts it with their private key` not good, public key is used for encryption.  A could create a hash of a plaintext message and sign the hash with its private key (B will do the same). The hashes must be the same without revealing original message and signature proves that B knew the plaintext. The ciphertext should not provide/prove any information and should be undistinguishable from random data

Comment: My mistake, its doesn't have to be rsa